# Specific arrow using ::after & ::before pseudo elements with IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7, pseudo-element

Once again I have a problem using IE7.

I try to use ::after & ::before pseudo elements too add an arrow at the end of the cursor of my entry.
It is not shown in the code from the jsfiddle but the user has to be completely free in the way he wants to design the arrow (size, type, color, etc.).

See the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/22hNA/6/

```
<div style=" " 
             id="progress" 
             class="progress">
            <div unselectable="on" style="
                                          color:rgb(0,94,149); 
                                          border-color: rgb(0,0,151);
                                          border-style: dashed;" 
                 id="progressAmount" 
                 class="amount progressamount pseudoelement-after rightRightPlainArrow">

                    <div class="arrow_box ">
                        28
                    </div>

    .progressamount:after, .progressamount:before,
div[class*=pseudoelement] > .before, div[class*=pseudoelement] > .after  {
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

/* ------------------------------------------------ right-right plain arrow ------------------------------------------------ */
.rightRightPlainArrow:after,
.rightRightPlainArrow[class*='pseudoelement'] > .after {
    border-right-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    border-width: 13px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    right: -13px;
}
/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

And its full screen result

http://jsfiddle.net/22hNA/6/embedded/result/

As you can guess it works fine on IE8+ and Chrome but because these pseudo elements are not supported by IE7, it doesn't work with this version.

I tried a lot of different things, like using IE8.js or a jquery pseudo plugin, but which does not seem to work in my case (and IE8.js put a big mess in my page). And I also tried another jquery pseudo plugin from luke lutman but I don't know if it doesn't work or if I simply don't understand how to use it.
The reason can be that I already am using a lot of different tools to make things works with IE7, like a filter for the gradient or the CSSPIE lib for the radius and the shadow (which is not in the fiddle).

Is my example clear enough ? 
I tried to simplify it but it originally is quite a mess to simplify because I also am using a lot of private scripts in it.

How can I make this little arrow appear with IE7 (and use the ::after & ::before pseudo el) ?

Does it sometimes simply happen to be impossible ?

Thank you,
Tim

Comment: Will the world end if a *seven-year-old* browser doesn't display fancy little arrows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try UTF-8 Unicode block arrows or triangles

css

```
content : "◀";
```

see

http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=9600&number=128

http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8576

Comment: Oh yeah why not, I can use this alternative in the case of IE7. The only thing is that the user has to be completely free in the way he wants to design the arrow (the entire control actually) and chose the type, size and color, but it doesn't seem to be possible in this very particular case...

Comment: The various options ("type") should be found at the links at post. `css` `color` should be able to be set same as ordinary css property, i.e.g., `color:blue;` ("color"). Size should be able to be set by ordinary css as well, i.e.g., `font-weight:500;`, etc. BTW, **_the user has to be completely free in the way he wants to design the arrow (the entire control actually) and chose the type, size and color_** does not appear as to be included as part of requirement at original post ? Perhaps edit OP to include, describe all aspects of requirement ? Thanks

Comment: _the user has to be completely free in the way he wants to design the arrow (the entire control actually) and chose the type, size and color -user3665301_  .                                                      Tried `canvas` element ?

Comment: Yes I forgot to specify this and it is important. But your first idea is interesting and I am going to have a look at it right now and see what I can do. And otherwise have a look at the canvas element. Thanks @guest , I ll keep you up to date :)